# How to flatten nested tree of objects?

Tags: java, kotlin

I have next models structure:

```
data class Person(
    val id: UUID,
    val firstName: String,
    val lastName: String,
    val email: String,
    val login: String,
    val passwordHash: String,
    val roles: Set<Role>
)

data class Role(
    val id: UUID,
    val name: String,
    val childrenRoles: List<Role>?
)
```

And trying to flatten nested structure of objects to get list of resolved roles. But have no idea how to do it in functional style. Tried several wrong approaches:

```
 fun flattenAllRoles(rootRoles: List<Role>?, roles: List<Role>?): List<Role>? {
        return if (rootRoles == null && roles == null && roles?.isEmpty() == true) {
            null
        } else {
            roles
                ?.mapNotNull { rootRoles?.plus((flattenAllRoles(rootRoles, it.childrenRoles))) }
                ?.flatten()
                ?.toList() as List<Role>?
        }
    }

    fun resolve(rootPerson: Person): List<Role>? {
        val rootRoles = rootPerson.roles.toList()
        return flattenAllRoles(
            rootRoles = rootRoles,
            roles = rootRoles.mapNotNull { it.childrenRoles }.flatten().toList()
        )
    }
```

Would you kindly help me with it?

Comment: Can you add a sample input and output in the question?

Comment: @ArpitShukla what kind of sample do you need?

Answer (score 3):

Try collect the children recursively and add them to the list of parent roles passed as a parameter (since `plus()` returns a new list this doesn't change the parameter so you're safe):

```
fun flattenAllRoles(roles: List<Role>?): List<Role>? {
  return roles?.plus(roles?.mapNotNull { flattenAllRoles(it.childrenRoles) }
                          ?.flatten()
                          ?.toList())
}
```

Assuming we have the following role tree:

```
 A
 +- AA
  +- AAA
  +- AAB
 +- AB
  +- ABA
  +- ABB
```

You should now get a list of A, AA, AB, AAA, AAB, ABA, ABB.

How this works:

- initial call: A is added to `list1`
- recursion 1: AA and AB are added `list2` (passed as parameters)
- recursion 2 (from 1): AAA and AAB are added `list3` (passed as parameters)
- recursion 3 (from 1): ABA and ABB are added `list4` (passed as parameters)
- back to recursion 1: the collected lists `list3` and `list4` are flattened and added to `list2` which now contains AA, AB, AAA, AAB, ABA and ABB.
- back to initial call: the returned `list2` is flattened and added to `list1` which finally is returned.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a lot of nesting, you might want to avoid re-creating list objects over and over.

By providing a function similar to `flatMapTo` of the Kotlin stdlib, you can achieve this goal.

```kotlin
fun Role.flattenedTo(destination: MutableCollection<Role>) {
    destination.add(this)

    childrenRoles?.forEach { it.flattenedTo(destination) }
}

fun Role.flattened(): List<Role> {
    val allRoles = mutableListOf<Role>()

    this.flattenedTo(allRoles)

    return allRoles
}
```

If you want to convert a nullable list of Roles, you might add this little function to it.

```kotlin
fun flattenAllRoles(roles: List<Role>?): List<Role>? = roles?.flatMap { it.flattened() }
```

However, you might rather want to add an extension to the `Person` class I assume.

```kotlin
fun Person.allRoles() = roles.flatMap { it.flattened() }
```

Comment: Yep, good catch. But currently database don't have a lot of nested roles. In that case I can use approach with re-creation of roles.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a typical functional way to do this stuff in general using tail recursion:

```
data class Role(val name: String, val childRoles: List<Role> = emptyList())

val structure = listOf(
    Role("A", listOf(
        Role("AA"),
        Role("AB")
    )),
    Role("B", listOf(
        Role("BA", listOf(
            Role("BAA")
        )),
        Role("BB")
    ))
)

tailrec fun collectRoles(remaining: List<Role>, collected: List<Role>): List<Role> {
    if (remaining.isEmpty()) return collected
    val head = remaining.first()
    val tail = remaining.drop(1)
    return collectRoles(head.childRoles.plus(tail), collected.plus(head))
}

fun main() {
    println(collectRoles(structure, emptyList()).joinToString { it.name })
}

>> A, AA, AB, B, BA, BAA, BB
```

You're basically processing a queue of items (`remaining`) - I've used the terms `head` and `tail` since they get used a lot in functional programming, the head is basically the item at the front of the list, and the tail is the remaining list (which could be empty). So you pop off the head, and add its child roles to the processing queue. Then you add the head to the completed list, and run the function again on that new state.

By always adding the child roles to the front of the processing queue (`head.childRoles.plus(tail)`) you're ensuring they get processed next, so you end up with **depth-first** traversal. If you add them to the end (`tail.plus(head.childRoles)`) you ensure every layer that's been added gets processed before any of that layer's children, so you get **breadth-first** traversal.

---

The `tailrec` modifier is an optimisation for tail-recursive functions, where the **last thing** a function does is call itself. Because it doesn't have any more work to do when the call returns, there's no state to remember and the compiler doesn't need to maintain a stack of function calls, it can just flatten that out to something more like iteration. If **A** calls **B** which calls **C**, and all **B** is going to do is return the result of **C** to **A**, the compiler can just cut out the middleman and pass the result from **C** directly to **A**!

It's more efficient than normal recursion, and because you don't need to build a call stack, there's no limit to how deep the recursion can go - no need to worry about the dreaded **stack overflow**. That's probably not important for what you're doing here, but generally speaking, a lot of functional programming relies on this recursive approach to breaking problems down, where the number of steps required could be arbitrarily huge, so it's good to know how to do it. Turning that recursive call into a tail call (where it's the last operation in the function) might require you to do things a little differently, and this *processing queue / results list* approach is a typical way to do it!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following function to flatten the entire hierarchy:

```kotlin
fun List<Role>.flattenRoles(): List<Role> {
    return this + map { it.childrenRoles?.flattenRoles() ?: emptyList() }.flatten()
}
```

[try it yourself](https://pl.kotl.in/vWOBlGiHw)

- `flattenRoles` is an extension function on `List<Role>`. (You can handle the nullability of this list at call site).
- `it.childrenRoles?.flattenRoles()` returns the flattened list of all children roles. If `childrenRoles` is `null`, an `emptyList()` is used.
- All the roles in the list are mapped to the list of their `childrenRoles` and then that `List<List<Role>>` is flattened using `flatten`.